# django getting data from other model with fk

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

i have this models

```
class Bus(models.Model):
    bus_name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=10, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
__________________________________________________

class Soc(models.Model):
value = models.FloatField(...)
bus = models.ForeignKey(Bus....)

__________________________________________________

class Iso(models.Model):
value = models.FloatField(...)
bus = models.ForeignKey(Bus....)
```

What i want is access to  iso value and soc value from the bus model
but i dont know how ... any ideas??

Comment: Since this is a `ForeignKey` it means there can be zero, one or *more* `Soc`/`Iso`s for the *same* `Bus`...

Comment: yes , so what i want is in one query obtain all the data in iso and soc for one bus something like this

bus=bus.bus.filter(id=1)
bus.soc (values for bus1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bus = Bus.bus.filter(id=2)
bus3 = bus.values('soc__soc_value')
```

this is how i access to the values of the others models